# Close $mdDialog on browser back button click - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-material

I currently have a `$mdDialog` that when opened is full page and has a form within it. When the user clicks cancel the `$mdDialog` is closed by calling this function

```
$mdDialog.cancel();
```

However, I want to also close the `$mdDialog` when a user clicks the browsers back button, this is what I am looking to do

```
backButtonWasClicked = function() }
  $mdDialog.cancel();
}
```

How can this be done? I've thought about putting a hash in the URL when the `$mdDialog` shows like `mywebsite.com/page#dialog` and then somehow when the user clicks the back button it can see this hash and close the dialog and remove the hash. I am not sure if that is the best way.

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS Material - Dialog Close Using Phone "back" Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594555/angularjs-material-dialog-close-using-phone-back-button)

Comment: @Blizwire this post has nothing to do with mobile. Also, the provided solutions for your question do not solve the issue I was having.

Comment: the answer for the linked question is platform agnostic. Works the same regardless if the user clicks a physical "back" button on their device or the browser back button. The issue can be dealt with in the same way, by listening to rootscope's state change event and triggering the cancel method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to this for anyone who may want the same functionality.

This is the code that creates my `$mdDialog`

```
$scope.showOrderFormOverlay = function (ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
        templateUrl: '/Partials/dialog.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose: false,
        escapeToClose: false,
        fullscreen: true,
        focusOnOpen: false,
        onComplete: function () {
            $('.md-dialog-container').addClass('fullscreen');
            $location.hash("this-can-be-whatever");
        }
    });
};
```

I injected `$location` into the controller that creates my `$mdDialog`. Then, I added this line `$location.hash("this-can-be-whatever")` into the `onComplete` function. This adds a hash to the current url `mywebsite.com/page`, so after you open the `$mdDialog` it will look like this `mywebsite.com/page#this-can-be-whatever`.

Then inside of my `$mdDialog`'s controller I added this function,

```
window.onpopstate = function () {
    if (window.location.hash == "") {
        $mdDialog.cancel();  // Cancel the active dialog
    }
}
```

This will remove the hash from the url and close the `$mdDialog`.

Comment: -1 since this answer is using somewhat of a hack with window.location hash to keep track of the users behaviour. There's already a built in event for when the user changes state (e.g. by clicking the browsers back button). Please see my answer below for a proper angular solution.

Comment: @Blizwire, why I can't see your solution?

Comment: @azerafati people voted it down and removed it so its not visible any more. Anyway the answer was referencing this link if you're interested. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594555/angularjs-material-dialog-close-using-phone-back-button/34844681#34844681